# Faucet spout perlator: worth it?

Tags: plumbing, tools, water, faucet

I've seen the following perlator and similars (also plastic ones) on some shopping sites. They claim it can decrease water consumption up to 40%. Is it possible? Is it worth to try?

[image]

Comment: If you are filling a pot, or your sink, it will take the same amount of water anyway.

It **will** reduce the amount of water you use when washing your hands, or rinsing dishes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've had a couple of these over the years and found that their biggest benefit was the ability to convert to a spray for better rinsing of dishes if your sink doesn't have a separate sprayer, not so much their water-saving ability.  Even though a 40% reduction sounds like a lot, your kitchen sink doesn't use that much water to begin with compared to, say, your shower or clothes washer.  So reducing your kitchen sink usage by 40% may not produce noticeable results on your water bill.

Comment: I'd echo what Mike said. We have one like this, mainly because we don't have a spray head. This is a cheap and simple way to add a spray head. That it may save some water is a bonus.